# Parser optimization using asynchrony in Python

Tags: python-3.x, parsing, selenium-webdriver, python-asyncio, pyppeteer

I have a task to parse every second data from a website and check if there is fresh news. I also have a condition that the parser should execute js. I tried to implement this with requests_html, but as I realized my site uses HTTP2, which is not supported by this library. I decided to use pyppeteer for scraping. Here is my code:

```
import asyncio
import datetime
from csv import DictWriter
from time import time

from pyppeteer import launch
from fake_useragent import UserAgent
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup


async def create_browser():
    browser = await launch({'headless': True,
                            'executablePath': '/usr/bin/google-chrome-stable'})
    return browser


async def scrape_page(browser, ua):
    page = await browser.newPage()
    await page.setUserAgent(ua.random)
    await page.goto(f'https://announcements.bybit.com/en-US/?category=&page=1&{int(time())}')
    visit_time = datetime.datetime.now()
    html_content = await page.content()
    return html_content, visit_time


class Parsing:
    def __init__(self, domain):
        self.domain = domain
        self.last_news_title = ""

    def __call__(self, html_code, visit_time):
        soup = BeautifulSoup(html_code, 'lxml')
        news_data = soup.select_one('a.no-style span:only-child')
        news_title = " ".join(news_data.text.strip().split())
        if news_title != self.last_news_title:
            self.last_news_title = news_title
            link = f"{self.domain}{news_data.find_parent('a')['href']}"
            d = {'time': visit_time, 'title': self.last_news_title, 'link': link}
            with open('data/news.csv', 'a') as file:
                writer = DictWriter(file, fieldnames=list(d.keys()), dialect='excel')
                writer.writerow(d)
            print("Новая новость записана")
        else:
            print("Новых новостей нет")


async def job(parsing, browser, ua):
    html_code, visit_time = await scrape_page(browser, ua)
    parsing(html_code, visit_time)


async def main():
    start = time()
    parsing = Parsing("https://announcements.bybit.com")
    our_browser = await create_browser()
    user_agent = UserAgent()
    try:
        while True:
            await job(parsing, our_browser, user_agent)
            await asyncio.sleep(1)
            print(time()-start)
    except:
        await our_browser.close()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    asyncio.run(main())
```

As I noticed with time(), the time per check for new data on the site is 3-4 seconds. This seems too long to me.  Besides, I implemented similar logic on Selenium (synchronous, as I understood, it doesn't support asynchronous) and it showed approximately the same results.  Is my code asynchronous?

Comment: Your code is not asynchronous.  asyncio.run creates a task automatically.  That would be `main`.  You never create a second task, so there is no multitasking.  See the docs for asyncio.create_task, asyncio.TaskGroup, or loop.create_task (where `loop` is a running asyncio event loop).